# What is the best way to obtain the file from binary attachment in Soap WSA response on C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, response

I am trying to obtain the attached file from the following response of a Soap with attachments response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 22 Nov 2021 08:52:38 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.0
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-XSS-Protection: 1;mode=block
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin,strict-origin-when-cross-origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/xml"; charset=utf-8; boundary=e5dec305-c274-4dae-8cf4-23f373e1ef23; start="<null>
    "
Response_time: D=1078981 t=1637571157195291
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=500
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


--e5dec305-c274-4dae-8cf4-23f373e1ef23
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID:
    <null>

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://administracion.gob.es/punto-unico-notificaciones/respuestaPeticionAcceso" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <SOAP-ENV:Header>
                <wsse:Security>
                    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Id-6b1b22fa-a028-4bb0-83f9-3d2ad9111c1b">
                        <wsu:Created>2021-11-22T08:52:38.000Z</wsu:Created>
                        <wsu:Expires>2021-11-22T08:57:38.000Z</wsu:Expires>
                    </wsu:Timestamp>
                    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="CertId-3d2079c6-222b-4bab-88f6-33dd214c4f8d">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
                    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <ds:SignedInfo>
                            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                            <ds:Reference URI="#Id-7ac15be4-4e93-439b-a3e2-3278ab3a6d32">
                                <ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                                </ds:Transforms>
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                                <ds:DigestValue>6Mg5Y=</ds:DigestValue>
                            </ds:Reference>
                            <ds:Reference URI="#Id-6b1b22fa-a028-4bb0-83f9-3d2ad9111c1b">
                                <ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                                </ds:Transforms>
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                                <ds:DigestValue>[...]</ds:DigestValue>
                            </ds:Reference>
                        </ds:SignedInfo>
                        <ds:SignatureValue>[...]</ds:SignatureValue>
                        <ds:KeyInfo>
                            <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                                <wsse:Reference URI="#CertId-3d2079c6-222b-4bab-88f6-33dd214c4f8d" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
                            </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        </ds:KeyInfo>
                    </ds:Signature>
                </wsse:Security>
            </SOAP-ENV:Header>
            <SOAP-ENV:Body wsu:Id="Id-7ac15be4-4e93-439b-a3e2-3278ab3a6d32">[...]
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
        --e5dec305-c274-4dae-8cf4-23f373e1ef23--
Content-Type: application/zip; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: [...]
BINARYDATA
```

I have obtained the response with this method

```
public HttpWebResponse SendRequest2(string Xmlrequest, string SOAPaction)
{
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_endPoint);
            webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Use", "literal");
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Parameters-style", "Wrapped");
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.Connection = "Keep - Alive";
            webRequest.Accept = "/*/";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", SOAPaction);

            var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Xmlrequest);
            webRequest.ContentLength = content.Length;
            using (var stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            }
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            return responseString ;
        }
```

I have tried unsuccessfully to capture the binarydata in a string variable, obtaining only gibberish. Havent found any good documentation on how to get the attachments on C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the reply provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449174/get-attachment-from-soap-response-and-save-file) by Dhaval Kateliya was the way to go. I add here my version of the method.

```
public string SendRequestMultipart(string Xmlrequest, string SOAPaction)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_endPoint);
                webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;
               

                var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Xmlrequest);
                webRequest.ContentLength = content.Length;
                using (var stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
                }
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
                var contenttype = response.Headers.Get("Content-Type");
                if (response.Headers.Get("Content-Type") != "text/xml; charset=utf-8")
                {
                    String retVal = readMultipart(response).Result;


                    return retVal.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    string answertring =
                        new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                    return answertring ;
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                string error = GetSoapFault(ex);
                return error;
            }

            async Task<string> readMultipart(HttpWebResponse httpResponse)
            {
                try
                {
                    var content = new StreamContent(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
                    content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", httpResponse.ContentType);
                    MultipartMemoryStreamProvider multipart = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => multipart = content.ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result,
                       CancellationToken.None,
                       TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, // guarantees separate thread
                       TaskScheduler.Default)
                       .Wait();
                    String json = await multipart.Contents[0].ReadAsStringAsync();
                    string path = @"mypath";
              
                    byte[] fileData = multipart.Contents[1].ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, fileData);
                    return json;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
```